# Socket.io not connecting via https

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm running a socket server on port 3000 and is proxied by Nginx. My Nginx's config:

```sh
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.domain.com www.example.domain.com;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    keepalive_timeout         60;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:TLSSL:30m;
    ssl_session_timeout       10m;
    ssl_buffer_size                32k;
    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security max-age=315360000;

    location /my-socket-path/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.domain.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

My socket server's config (i use NestJS):

```js
@WebSocketGateway({ transports: ["websocket"], namespace: "my-namespace" })
```

Then I write a simple socket.io client to connect to the socket server:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("https://example.domain.com/my-namespace" {
    path: "/my-socket-path",
    transports: ["websocket"],
    reconnectionAttempts: 30,
    reconnectionDelay: 2000,
    reconnection: true,
});

socket.connect();

socket.io.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

When running the client, i get this error:

```sh
Error Error: websocket error
    at WS.onError (file:///home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/build/esm-debug/transport.js:30:21)
    at WebSocket.ws.onerror (file:///home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/build/esm-debug/transports/websocket.js:79:37)
    at WebSocket.onError (/home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:220:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at abortHandshake (/home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:909:15)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:753:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:647:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:127:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22) {
  type: 'TransportError',
  description: ErrorEvent {
    [Symbol(kTarget)]: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
      _closeTimer: null,
      _extensions: {},
      _protocol: '',
      _readyState: 2,
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      _bufferedAmount: 0,
      _isServer: false,
      _redirects: 0,
      _url: 'wss://example.domain.com/my-socket-path/?EIO=4&transport=websocket',
      _req: [ClientRequest],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
    [Symbol(kError)]: Error: Unexpected server response: 502
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/javascript/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:753:7)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:647:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:127:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
        at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
        at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23),
    [Symbol(kMessage)]: 'Unexpected server response: 502'
  }
}
```

UPD:
Nginx access log:

```sh
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [18/Apr/2022:14:16:49 +0700] "GET /my-socket-path/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "-"
```

Nginx error log:

```sh
2022/04/18 14:16:49 [error] 51391#51391: *140947 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.domain.com, request: "GET /my-socket-path/?EIO=4&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?EIO=4&transport=websocket", host: "example.domain.com"
```

I think the 502 error is due to Nginx's config but i haven't figured out which is the cause. Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the corresponding nginx error log entry to your question?

Comment: @IvanShatsky I updated nginx access log and error log. Sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the path of socket's config. Correct socket client config:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("https://example.domain.com/my-namespace" {
    path: "/my-socket-path/socket.io",
    transports: ["websocket"],
    reconnectionAttempts: 30,
    reconnectionDelay: 2000,
    reconnection: true,
});

socket.connect();

socket.io.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```